# Using ".getTag()" is not working when implementing Google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm starting to learn how to work with android studio and I am stuck when I am trying to implement Google maps.

I'm having this code but I don't know why my `.getTag()` doesn't work, do I have to implement something? Any help would be appreciated.

My Home.java where I can navigate to other fragments:

```
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Gravity;

import com.example.flow.displayClasses.BalansScreens.BalansFragment;
import com.example.flow.displayClasses.GroupScreens.GroupsFragment;
import com.example.flow.displayClasses.LendGoodsScreens.LendGoodsFragment;
import com.example.flow.displayClasses.WebscrapingScreens.GoogleMapsFragment;

import com.example.flow.displayClasses.ContactUsScreen.ContactUsFragment;
import com.example.flow.displayClasses.NightmodeScreen.NightmodeFragment;
import com.example.flow.displayClasses.SettingsScreen.SettingsFragment;
import com.example.flow.displayClasses.FriendsScreen.FriendsFragment;
import com.example.flow.displayClasses.TermsAndConditionsScreen.TermsFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        TermsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        SettingsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ContactUsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        NightmodeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,

         {

    DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bottom_navigation);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



        FriendsFragment friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                friendsFragment,
                friendsFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.menuRight) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_friends) {

            FriendsFragment cameraFragment = FriendsFragment.newInstance("some1", "some2");
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            cameraFragment,
                            cameraFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            settingsFragment,
                            settingsFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_nightmode) {

            NightmodeFragment nightmodeFragment = new NightmodeFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            nightmodeFragment,
                            nightmodeFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {

            ContactUsFragment contactUsFragment = new ContactUsFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            contactUsFragment,
                            contactUsFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_termsandconditions) {

            TermsFragment blankFragment = new TermsFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            blankFragment,
                            blankFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_balans) {

            BalansFragment balansFragment = new BalansFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            balansFragment,
                            balansFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_review) {

            GoogleMapsFragment reviewFragment = new GoogleMapsFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            reviewFragment, reviewFragment.getTag()

                    ).commit();
        }

        else if (id == R.id.nav_goods) {

            LendGoodsFragment lendGoodsFragment = new LendGoodsFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            lendGoodsFragment,
                            lendGoodsFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();
        }

        else if (id == R.id.nav_groups) {

            GroupsFragment groupsFragment = new GroupsFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out)
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                            groupsFragment,
                            groupsFragment.getTag()
                    ).commit();
        }




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String data) {
        Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }


}
```

My fragment where I want to use Google maps:

```
package com.example.flow.displayClasses.WebscrapingScreens;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.flow.R;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class GoogleMapsFragment  extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_mapsgoogle);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }



    // public GoogleMapsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    //}

/*
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_googleMaps, container, false);
    }*/

}
```

We are using fragments because we want a navigation bar on the bottom, but I was wondering if there is an easier way. This is the look we currently have and that we want but we are using fragments, is this the correct way?

[the look of our app currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX1rj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace fragment like this

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, int containerId) {
        isReplaced = true;
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(containerId, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```